# Стиль кнопок css как на демо

Tags: html, css, html5, css3, css-animation

как сделать стиль кнопок как на демо [этого](http://www.os-templates.com/free-website-templates/kelaby) сайта (перейдите по ссылке и там желтая кнопка чтобы посмотреть демо). На картинке айсберга две кнопки. Одна голубая и становится прозрачной при наведении, вторая прозрачная и становится голубой

Comment: сделать только спомощью css? Или какой-то фреймворк используется?

Comment: А вообще посмотрите код кнопок, там все видно.

Comment: css, посмотрел - попробовал. не выходит именно такой результат

Comment: нет, вы меня не правильно поняли, на эту желтую кнопку надо нажать и там откроется Демо версия сайта и там 2 кнопки 1 голубая, 1 прозрачная. Их стили мне нужны

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Код напрямую с их сайта:

```css
.inline *:last-child {
    margin-right: 0;
}
.btn {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 8px 18px 10px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border: 1px solid;
}

.btn, .btn.inverse:hover, a .icon, a.inverse:hover .icon {
    color: #FFF;
    background-color: #1C7AA8;
    border-color: #1C7AA8;
    transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}

.nospace {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
.btn:hover, .btn.inverse, a:hover .icon, a.inverse .icon {
    color: inherit;
    background-color: transparent;
    border-color: inherit;
    transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<footer>
<ul class="nospace inline pushright">
<li><a class="btn" href="http://www.os-templates.com/free-website-templates">Vitae suspendisse</a></li>
<li><a class="btn inverse" href="http://www.os-templates.com/free-website-templates">Molestie semper</a></li>
</ul>
</footer>
```